# How to enable trust proxy in express. Nestjs app

Tags: proxy, ip, nestjs

I am learning nestjs and, building an app but my ip is behind the proxy,

Nestjs documentation says enable the trust proxy in express,

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting

I am getting trouble how to do that and then how to find the IP.

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```js
import { NestExpressApplication } from "@nestjs/platform-express"

const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

Credit:

[Nestjs Docs Offical](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#platform)

[Nestjs Docs But Not Offical](https://5fb51d4988c6ba0007e5e155--docs-nestjs.netlify.app/techniques/security)

[Express behind proxies](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)

Comment: So you have to add this code in main.js ?

Comment: Yes, You must to declare type for app variable know definitely type.

Comment: Suffice to say, you have to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` to your NGINX Server Location Block in case you are using NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

for **Fastify** adapter trustProxy accept true, number, array of CIDRs, and string of comma separated CIDRs and should be passed like that:

```js
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({
      // @see https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#trustproxy
      trustProxy: process.env.TRUST_PROXY?.match(/\d/)
        ? +process.env.TRUST_PROXY
        : process.env.TRUST_PROXY,
    }),
  );
  await app.listen(port, process.env.ADDRESS); // ADDRES = "undefined" or "0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: ...question was about express, not Fastify.

Comment: Google shows this question when I looked for fastify. It's just matter of easiness to find the answer. Somebody can find it relevanted as I did.

Comment: I was looking for a fastify answer and landed here, so yes it was helpful, thanks @Grigory